# how get data from DialogFragment to Mainactivity

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

**How con I get text from TextView in DialogFragment to MainActivity or how i make event in MainActivity when Button in DialogFragment clicked.** pleas help me i tried like this in below:but it dose not work what is the problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b; Button b2; String name;
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        name = data.getStringExtra("name").toString();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,name+ "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        b2.setText(name);}});}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
        return true;}
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        fragment afr = new fragment();
        afr.setTargetFragment(afr, 1);
        afr.show(manager, "dialog");
        return true;}}

 class fragment extends DialogFragment {
     View v;  Intent intent; EditText t1; Button b1; String name;
     @Nullable
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
         t1=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.t1);
         b1=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.b1);
         intent = new Intent();
         int resultCode = 1;
         getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, intent);
         getDialog().dismiss();
         b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 name=t1.getText().toString();
                 intent.putExtra("name", name);
                fragment.this.dismiss();
             }});   return v;}}
```

Comment: It is still Fragment to Activity communication... Which is pretty good described in online tutorials or similar questions

Answer (score 0):

You can use interfaces. 
Declare interface in fragment and implement it in MainActivity.

> https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

In DialogFragment declare

```
public IDialogCallback {
   void onTextWritted(String text);
   void onDialogBtnClick()
}
```

Then declare field in Dialog:

```
OnDialogCallback mCallback
```

Later:

```
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mCallback = (ITailLiftCallback) context;
    }
```

Now you can call `mCallback.onTextWritted()` or `mCallback.onDialogBtnClick` in DialogFragment. In first case you may put text from TextView and second - put it in OnClickListener of a button.

Then make `MainActivity implements IDialogCallback` and it is all! :)